# What should I give as the reasons for leaving my last job? I was fired while on sick leave, so been confused since

Tags: applications, sickness

I have only had one proper job, it was full time shift work at a factory. I was a temporary worker there and I declared dyslexia and Meares-Irlen syndrome (MIS) ahead of them even recieving my application via a job agency.

It was too much too fast - with the full-time shifts being rotary, and the environment was dazzling white which triggered me MIS headaches and migraines frequently, I was constantly tired and had a painful head during and after work. I was not sure how to communicate when I had migraines at work though, I found the job a let let alone working out how to communicate illness. I took breaks blindfolded to reduce the migraine, and would close my eyes for non-visual tasks like walking. I my manager the environment was too bright and what that meant, but that lead to nothing. I had found it hard to get a straight answer about what cleaning procedure they what for me to take my visual overlay aide into the workplace, which I formed them at interview I needed.

My work pace was good, and I wanted to do well. The contract was temporary to permenant.

After 7 weeks I began to develop a strange illness, sudden and intense sensitivity in the left hand/forearm area. I spoke to my manager who advised I left the workplace, I did within an hour. It was Christmas eve, so medical services and office hours were limited. I didn't get a diagnosis that day, and the problems worsened over the following week up to a point where I could not use my left hand, and had limp, and no idea why. I attempted to inform both my workplace and job agency [on the next working day] with a voicemail as the offices where shut and I had no access to an email address for the offices or my manager. The first day both re-opened, I was called early by the job agency. They said the employer fired me for 'learning slowly' and repeated themselves in saying it had nothing to do with be being ill.

I think I had little legal protection as I was temporary at that point. When at work, on the progress charts, it looked like I was going through learning material at a great pace. So the reasoning does not makes sense to me.

Due to my physical health I was unable to work for 4 consecutive weeks, beginning that christmas eve. I had booked some planned holiday time including christmas day while I was ill. I began to develop severe depression right after the depression that physical illness.

I originally wrote this post a few months after my last relapse of that physical illness occured, and when writing it orginally and ill I was afraid never be accepted by any employer. This experience had a big impact on my confidence.

Comment: "I was temporary at that point and had no workers rights at the point in time." - Workers' rights are not dependent upon tenure. Employers like to imply/lie about that though.

Answer (score 6):

Normally I go with something neutral enough that it doesn't sound bad, but is not a lie...

For example:

Fired for sick leave => I had some health issues at the time and was unable to continue. I'm much better now and ready to re-enter the workplace.

Fired during probation => The company was not the right fit for me.

If it comes up, do not lie about being let go (don't say fired), but make it clear that it was at a different time in your life.

Comment: I tought that "The company was not the right fit for me" was the universal polite way of saying "The reason I left my old job is none of your business" to a recruiter...

Answer (score 3):

I would just **tell the truth**, you got ill and the company let you go while you were ill.  It happens and is not as big of a deal as you may think.

Let interviewers know, if asked, that you used all the provided time off you could but it was not enough time for you to heal.  Follow this up with how healthy you are now and how eager you are to return to work.